# flashMessenger not found in Zend Framework 2

Tags: zend-framework2, flashmessenger

I am using the flash messenger plugin in Zend Framework 2. I can set messages in the controller's action, that's no problem:

```
$this->flashMessenger()->addMessage('You are now logged in.');
```

But when I try to call it in the view, as it is described in the official Zend Framework documentation (https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.view.helpers.flash-messenger.html), I get an error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Zend\Mvc\Controller\Plugin\FlashMessenger' not found in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/zend/vendor/zendframework/zend-view/src/Helper/Service/FlashMessengerFactory.php on line 33
```

I read the documentation and did not find any information about initialization before using it. What I can do is passing the messages to the view, but if the documentation says it is possible to use the plugin in the view, I would prefer to use it like that and not pass an array of messages to the view.

The module is also listed in my modules.config.php:

```
return [
    'Zend\ServiceManager\Di',
    'Zend\Session',
    'Zend\Mvc\Plugin\Prg',
    'Zend\Mvc\Plugin\Identity',
    'Zend\Mvc\Plugin\FlashMessenger',
    'Zend\Mvc\Plugin\FilePrg',
    'Zend\Mvc\I18n',
    'Zend\Mvc\Console',
    'Zend\Log',
    'Zend\Form',
    'Zend\Db',
    'Zend\Cache',
    'Zend\Router',
    'Zend\Validator',
    'Album',
    'Application',
    'User',
];
```

Comment: You linked to the docs for version 2.3. What version of Zend Framework are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 2.4 (installed it last week). The documentation for 2.4 seems to be the same.

Comment: How did you install it? If by composer, could you provide the contents of the `composer.lock`? The modules here in here look very much like ZF3 for me :)

Comment: I installed it like it was described in the documentation of the current Zend version. I posted my composer.lock here: http://pastebin.com/0afuAWQB I did not know that there is a version 3 of ZF?